# How to use erlang-examples

Tags: erlang

I just downloaded Erlang using `apt-get` onto **Ubuntu 10.10**. How do I run the examples that come with Erlang (the examples you can get through `apt-get install erlang-examples`). I tried going to the directory where they were stored and compiling `ball.erl`, but I got this error:

```
ball.bea#: error writing file
error
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The directory where those examples are stored isn't writeable by normal users. To compile a `.erl` file, the compiler needs to be able to write out the compiled `.beam` file.

One way around this is to copy the files to a directory you *can* write to and compile them there:

```
$ mkdir erlex
$ cd erlex
$ cp /usr/lib/erlang/lib/gs-1.5.11/examples/src/* .
$ erlc *.erl
```

You need the `erlang-dev` package installed for that to work.

You can run the `ball` example like so:

```
$ erl -s ball
```

`ball` here is the module name, and the Erlang emulator defaults to calling the `start/0` function in that module, which is correct in this case.

You don't actually have to compile these examples, however. The Ubuntu `erlang-examples` package ships with them already compiled:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/erlang/lib/gs-1.5.11/examples/ebin
$ erl -s ball
```

After closing the GUI window in each, say `q().` to get out of the emulator. This may seem weird to you until you realize that everything about Erlang is designed with long uptimes in mind. The mere fact that the last process the emulator was running has stopped isn't enough reason for the BEAM emulator to shut itself down. Something else might be started in that same emulator later, after all.