# Erlang build failure: error writing file

Tags: build, erlang

I am new to Erlang and am trying to build the Erlang package. I am using R13B version. Its an old version but am using it because it already used in a pre-existing project.
I am getting the following err: 
...rlang/build/lib/hipe/rtl/../ebin/hipe_rtl.bea#: error writing file

I searched the internet and potential reason was lack of permission. The directory it is writing to my home directory.

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: We can certainly help, but we need more information. For example, what OS are you installing on? What command in the install process were you running when the error occurred? What is the full error message? The error in your question looks incomplete. Also, it would be helpful to see the other messages that were logged prior to the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use erlang-examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495756/how-to-use-erlang-examples)